# Tensorflow: Print contents of a tensor in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

How do I print to screen contents of a tensor defined as below

```
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> finalOutput;
```

and which is assigned value by running the following operation

```
tensorflow::Status run_status = session->Run({{"x",input_tensor}, 
                                                       {"keep_prob", keep_prob}},
                                                      {"prediction"},
                                                      {},
                                                  &finalOutput);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [example](https://gist.github.com/jimfleming/4202e529042c401b17b7#file-loader-cc-L48):

```
// The session will initialize the outputs
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

// Run the session, evaluating our "c" operation from the graph
status = session->Run(inputs, {"c"}, {}, &outputs);
if (!status.ok()) {
  std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
  return 1;
}

// Grab the first output (we only evaluated one graph node: "c")
// and convert the node to a scalar representation.
auto output_c = outputs[0].scalar<float>();

// (There are similar methods for vectors and matrices here:
// https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/public/tensor.h)

// Print the results
std::cout << outputs[0].DebugString() << "\n"; // Tensor<type: float shape: [] values: 30>
std::cout << output_c() << "\n"; // 30
```

Answer (score 8):

To print a *d*-dimensional tensorflow::Tensor *T*

```
#define printTensor(T, d) \
    std::cout<< (T).tensor<float, (d)>() << std::endl
```